# The property "OutboundTransportLocation" has a value with length greater than 256 characters

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a BizTalk HTTP adapter and it is sending an SMS. However, the body of the message may sometimes reach more than 256 characters and that's why we're encountering the following error whenever the message body exceeded 256 characters"

> The property "OutboundTransportLocation" has a value with length greater than 256 characters."

Is there anything I can do to prevent this issue and still send more than 256 characters?

Comment: Is `OutboundTransportLocation` a promoted property?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/feec5c10-79ed-456d-8f0e-33147d96fd7a/varible-mapping-on-wcfwebhttp-adapter-promoted-property-large-than-255-chars?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: Yes the OutboundTransportLocation is promoted properly. Is there anyway how to deal with this?

Comment: It looks like BizTalk automatically promotes the `OutboundTransportLocation` context property, and Promoted properties have a limit of 256 characters.  You might have to write a custom endpoint behavior that sets it from a  non-promoted context property to see if that gets around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the variable part to a `BtsHttpUrlMapping` construction, so the base path is always less than 256.